# How do I find the coordinates of every button on any webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, position

I found this code but I'm not sure where I'm meant to type that in or how to modify it to find the position of every button. Also, where are the results (coordinates) displayed?

```
function findPos(obj){
var curleft = 0;
var curtop = 0;

if (obj.offsetParent) {
do {
    curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
    curtop += obj.offsetTop;
   } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);

return {X:curleft,Y:curtop};
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want just button elements, or also input type button?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('button')` to get a list of all the buttons on your webpage. You can store the coordinates wherever you want (right now they are being returned from your function), but for demo purposes I will just log them to the console.

Also, you can greatly simplify your position-finding logic by leveraging [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), which return a DOMRect with precomputed `left` and `top` properties (`x` and `y` work in some browers, too, but are not supported in Chrome):

```js
function findPosition (element) {
  var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect()
  return {x: rect.left, y: rect.top }
}

var allCoordinates = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('button'), findPosition)

console.log(allCoordinates)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<button>First Button</button>
<button>Second Button</button>
<button>Third Button</button>
```

Comment: looks like your results are returning as `undefined`.

Comment: It looks like `x` and `y` are not supported in Chrome. I'm guessing that's the browser you are using; I updated the example to use the better-supported `left` and `top` properties instead.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getOffset( el ) {
    var _x = 0;
    var _y = 0;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
        _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
        _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    return { top: _y, left: _x };
}

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('button');
var elementsLen = elements.length;

for(var i=0; i<elementsLen; i++) {

  var x = getOffset( elements[i] ).left; 
  var y = getOffset( elements[i] ).top; 
  console.log('Position x :' +x);
  console.log('Position y:' +y);

}
```

```css
#some_id_2 {
  position:absolute;
  left:80px;
  top:45px;
}
```

```html
<button id="some_id_1">Some button</button>
<button id="some_id_2">Some other button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get `x` and `y` coordinates of any element on your webpage like.

```
<label for="x">X: </label><input type="text" name="x" id="x">
<label for="y">Y: </label><input type="text" name="y" id="y">
<button id="btn1">Click to get my coordinates</button>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("x"),
    y = document.getElementById("y");

var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    x.value = btn1.offsetLeft;
    y.value = btn1.offsetTop;
});
</script>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cte52ta1/

Comment: The OP's *findPos* function is more appropriate. This doesn't seem to answer the question: "*… to find the position of every button*".

Comment: I understand that it does not find coordinates of all elements in my example, though I think it is better to show how to do it for one element and let them modify/use it according to their own needs. What do you think?

Comment: The OP already has a very similar function for finding position, neither are particularly good as they don't allow for scrolling. Yours also doesn't allow for parent element offsets, so your answer doesn't add anything to what the OP already knows.